# Need regex to separate comma separated values (Interface list from a router query output)

Tags: java, regex

I have an input like this

`RX Only            : Gi1/0/15,Gi1/0/20,Gi1/0/17`

I want to capture `1/0/15`, `1/0/20`, `1/0/17` from this. But this input changes. Sometimes there are only 2 comma separated values, sometimes 1 sometimes more than 3.

The regex I came up with only captures the first group. If I use the non-greedy operator, then it captures last. What regex should I use to capture all these groups separately.

The language used would be Java.

Comment: Why not just split on the comma and remove the "Gi" from the start of the string? Sounds easier than faffing around with regex...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's often easier to just write the regex for the substrings you are interested in, then repeatedly use `Matcher.find()`, as opposed to trying to write a regex that matches the entire string and pulling what you want from a complex arrangement of groups.

assuming what you are looking for are triples of three numbers separated by "/", then,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+/\\d+/\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
while (m.find()) {
  // your triple is in group 0
  System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a man a fish ... or

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to use regex here? If data formats are quite similar you can just use `indexOf` function combined with `substring`. You will have to find the `:` character and start finding comas starting from the next character. Then you check the position of `\n` and use the smaller index in order to retrieve a substring.